# how to access key pair value of query result in php

Tags: php, parsing, php-5.6

I am trying to get the value of `currentPdfDownload` and `max_download_limit` from my `$result`  array variable

`var_dump($result);` output:-

```
 array(1) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#1529 (2) {
            ["currentPdfDownload"]=>
            string(2) "42"
            ["max_download_limit"]=>
            string(2) "20"
          }
        }
```

I try this:

```
echo $result['currentPdfDownload']." ".$result['max_download_limit'];
```

But it does not give any result.

Please highlight what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: its inside another dimension `array(1) {
          [0]=>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
echo $result[0]->currentPdfDownload." ".$result[0]->max_download_limit;
```

Note:- Your array have an index 0 and on that index it have an object array so you need to use `[0]` and `->` to fetch it's indexes as property of an object